# How to hide leading zero in printf

Tags: c, double, printf

The following outputs `0.23`. How do I get it to simply output `.23`?

```
printf( "%8.2f" , .23 );
```

Comment: What do you get when you use "%.2f" ?  I haven't coded in C in many years.

Comment: Subtract 0 from it ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The C standard says that for the `f` and `F` floating point format specifiers:

> If a decimal-point character appears, at least one digit appears before it.

I think that if you don't want a zero to appear before the decimal point, you'll probably have to do something like use `snprintf()` to format the number into a string, and remove the `0` if the formatted string starts with "0." (and similarly for "-0.").  Then pass that formatted string to our real output.  Or something like that.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to do it only using `printf`. The documention for `printf` says:

```
f  - "double" argument is output in conventional form, i.e.
     [-]mmmm.nnnnnn
     The default number of digits after the decimal point is six,
     but this can be changed with a precision field. If a decimal point
     appears, at least one digit appears before it. The "double" value is
     rounded to the correct number of decimal places.
```

Note the **If a decimal point appears, at least one digit appears before it**.

Therefore it seems you have to handcode your own formatter.

Answer (score 5):

Just convert it to an integer with the required accuracy

```c
double value = .12345678901; // input
int accuracy = 1000; // 3 digit after dot
printf(".%03d\n", (int)(value * accuracy) );
```

Output:

```
.123
```

[example source on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CfXEQJZs)

Comment: Fails for values like 0.01, 0.001, negative numbers, `value > INT_MAX/1000`, truncates rather than round.

Comment: Does not round up correctly. If `value = .1239`, then your approach produces `.123`, whereas `printf("%.3f\n", value);` produces `0.124`.

Comment: Rounding is different, depending part of the world you are living in. So, `.1239` becomes `.124`? Okay, what about `.1235`?

Answer (score 4):

```
double f = 0.23;

assert(f < 0.995 && f >= 0);  
printf(".%02u\n" , (unsigned)((f + 0.005) * 100));
```

Comment: This is the answer. Simple, efficient. "%2d" also works, if cast to an (int). Nice touch adding the .005 to round as %.2f does.

Comment: @Brent Foust Fails for `0.995 < f < 1.0` and for `0.0 < f < 0.095`

Comment: @chux: `.%02u` should fix `0 < f < 0.095` and if  `1 > f > 0.995` then there is no leading zero. Strictly speaking there are many values where `+0.005` code differs from `%.2f` (besides leading zero) e.g., `0.625` -> `.63` vs. `0.62`

Comment: Agree the changes cope with the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595738/how-to-hide-leading-zero-in-printf/2595875?noredirect=1#comment53726591_2595875) concerns.  With `(f + 0.005) * 100)`, would not `(f *100 + 0.5)` minimize the half-way case differences?

Comment: @chux: I don't see a significant improvement e.g., enumerating 1/1000s yields `41` diverging cases for `+0.005` vs. `40` cases for `+0.5`.

Comment: Good idea! Yet, this won't with with negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void printNoLeadingZeros(double theValue)
{
   char buffer[255] = { '\0' };

   sprintf(buffer, "%.2f", theValue);

   printf("%s\n", buffer + (buffer[0] == '0'));
}

int main()
{
   double values[] = { 0.23, .23, 1.23, 01.23, 001.23, 101.23 };
   int n           = sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0]);
   int i           = 0;

   while(i < n)
      printNoLeadingZeros(values[i++]);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Won't the `sizeof(values)` return the size of the pointer, not the actual array?

Comment: @ChristianMann: Depends on if you are in C or C++ mode of your compiler, I think.

Comment: Definitely the size of the array, regardless of language. Arrays are somewhat reluctant to to decay to pointers, and won't do so until you 'force' them to do so, for example by passing them as a parameter to a function accepting a pointer.

Comment: Good answer, as long as `theValue` is positive.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard C library doesn't provide this, so you have to write it yourself.  This isn't a rare, one-off requirement.  You'll need to write similar functions sooner or later to trim trailing zeros and to add in thousands-separators.  So, it pays to not just get the bytes of output you're looking for but to illustrate more generally how to write a strong library.  When doing so keep in mind:

1. figure out how you want to call it.  Something like this you write once but call
   a million times, so make the calling as easy as possible.
2. then make the test suite
   exercising all alternatives you can think of
3. while you're at it,
   just solve the problem forevermore so you never have to come back to
   it again (eg, don't hardcode width, precision, go ahead and make
   versions for leading-plus, e-format, and so on)
4. make it
   thread-safe even if you're not using threads (a specific case of
   point 3, actually)

So working backwards: Thread safety requires allocating storage on the stack, which must be done from the caller.  This isn't pretty or fun but just get used to it.  It's the C way.  Formats can have width, precision, some flags, and a conversion type (f, e, g).  So lets make width and precision parameters.  Rather than parameterizing the public API fully, I'll just have multiple entry points that say in the function name which flags and conversion type they use.

A pet peeve is that when passing in buffers to functions, the function will need to know the size.  But if you make that a separate parameter, it's a pain in the but as 1) the caller has to write it and 2) the caller can get it wrong.  So my personal style is to make a masking macro that assumes the buffer is a character array, not a pointer, and that uses sizeof() to pass the size into a more verbose version of the function taking the size.

Here's the mock-up of the simplest way I can think of to call it, with test cases.

(Note COUNT() is a macro I've used weekly for decades to get the number of elements in an array.  Standard C, should have had something like this.)

(Note I use a dialect of "Hungarian Notation" here.  "d" is a double. "a" is "array of."  "sz" is a NUL-terminated string buffer, while "psz" is a pointer to one.  The difference between these two is that "sz" can be used with COUNT() or sizeof() to get the array size, while "psz" cannot.  "i" is an integer and the specific variable "i" is used for looping.

```
double ad[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.2, 0.3, 0.45, 0.666, 888.99,
                -1.0, -2.2, -0.3, -0.45, -0.666, -888.99 };
char   szBuf[20];

for ( int i = 0; i < COUNT( ad ); i++ )
    printf( "%s\n", NoLeadingZeroF( 4, 2, ad[i], szBuf ) );

for ( int i = 0; i < COUNT( ad ); i++ )
    printf( "%s\n", NoLeadingZeroPlusF( 4, 2, ad[i], szBuf ) );
```

Now, the "f" and "+f" versions seem very similar, so lets have them both call an internal function.  Here are the functions, which take the buffer size, and macros that figure it out themselves.  (Parallel functions are also written for e and g formats.)

```
char* NoLeadingZeroFN( int iWidth, int iPrecision, double d, char* szBuf, int iBufLen ) {
  return NoLeadingZeroFmtN( "%*.*f", iWidth, iPrecision, d, szBuf, iBufLen );
}

char* NoLeadingZeroPlusFN( int iWidth, int iPrecision, double d, char* szBuf, int iBufLen ) {
  return NoLeadingZeroFmtN( "%+*.*f", iWidth, iPrecision, d, szBuf, iBufLen );
}


#define NoLeadingZeroF( width, precision, number, buf ) \
        NoLeadingZeroFN( ( width ), (precision ), ( number ), ( buf ), sizeof( buf ) ) 

#define NoLeadingZeroPlusF( width, precision, number, buf ) \
        NoLeadingZeroPlusFN( ( width ), (precision ), ( number ), ( buf ), sizeof( buf ) )
```

Finally the (internal) function that does the work.  Note that snprintf() needs a prepended underscore on Windows, but not on Unix.

```
char* NoLeadingZeroFmtN( char* szFmt, int iWidth, int iPrecision, double d, char* szBuf, int iBufLen ) {

#ifdef WIN32
  _snprintf( szBuf, iBufLen - 1, szFmt, iWidth, iPrecision, d );
#else
  snprintf( szBuf, iBufLen - 1, szFmt, iWidth, iPrecision, d );
#endif

  // Some snprintf()'s do not promise to NUL-terminate the string, so do it ourselves.
  szBuf[ iBufLen - 1 ] = '\0';

  // _snprintf() returns the length actually produced, IF the buffer is big enough.
  // But we don't know it was, so measure what we actually got.
  char* pcTerminator = strchr( szBuf, '\0' );

  for ( char* pcBuf = szBuf; *pcBuf && *pcBuf != '.'; pcBuf++ )
      if ( *pcBuf == '0' ) {
          memmove( pcBuf, pcBuf + 1, pcTerminator - pcBuf );
          break;
      }

  return szBuf;
}
```

The output is:

```
.00
1.00
2.20
.30
.45
.67
888.99
-1.00
-2.20
-.30
-.45
-.67
-888.99
+.00
+1.00
+2.20
+.30
+.45
+.67
+888.99
-1.00
-2.20
-.30
-.45
-.67
-888.99
```

Additional testing should verify that the functions work with buffers that are too small.

Answer (score 0):

It looks there is no easy solution. I would probably use something like code below. It is not the fastest method, however it should work with many different formats. It preserves number of char and position of dot too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fixprint(char *s)
{
        size_t i;
        i = 1;
        while (s[i]=='0' || s[i]==' ' || s[i]=='+' || s[i]=='-') {
                if (s[i]=='0') s[i]=' ';
                i++;
        }
}

int main()
{
        float x = .23;
        char s[14];
        sprintf(s,"% 8.2f",x);
        fixprint(s);
        printf("%s\n",s);
}
```

Comment: This does not work with what should be the easiest case `sprintf(s,"%.5f",x)` -- it seems to expect a space somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this using `printf()` So how can you achieve this perfectly?

**Here is my solution.**

`sprintf()` => to convert `float` to `string`.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
    char result[50];
    float num = 0.23;
    sprintf(result, "%.2f", num);

    char *str = result;
    int n = strspn(str, "0" );
    printf("Trimmed string is %s ", &str[n]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Trimmed string is .23
```