# Printf to Only Display decimal and one character after it

Tags: floating-point, printf

In my code I have a subtraction such as this: (numbers are arbitrary)

(2.3 + 6.0) - 8.3 = 0.0

I want to use the printf function in order to display this: .0 yet no matter what variation of printf I use, the best I can get is 0.0 using %.1f

Anyone know a way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595738/c-how-to-hide-leading-zero-in-printf

Comment: Had a feeling as well, thanks I will check it out

Comment: Especially the third answer (J.F. Sebastian) will most likely help you.

Answer (score 0):

snprintf could be used, but I would prefer having a simpler if/else logic. One more dependency on a lib is avoided. The 0.0 case is a unique case. snprintf might work out better if there are several conditions to handle.

```
if(num == 0.0f) {
    printf(".0");
}
else {
    printf(".2f", num);
}
```

Remember there are rare fp results that are near to zero, but not absolutely zero. So use with care.