# R: Can you use `base::format()` to format a number without a leading zero?

Tags: r

Can `base::format()` be used to format a number without the zero before the decimal point for numbers between -1 and 1?

Here is what I would like to see:

```r
format(0.5, ...)
#> ".5"

format(-0.5, ...)
#> "-.5"
```

What would the arguments be to make this happen?

Thank you!

Comment: This post has some suggestions but nothing with `base::format` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643391/how-to-remove-leading-0-in-a-numeric-r-variable

Comment: Thanks for the link. For complicated reasons, I do need it using the `format()` function.

Comment: Related (not R), but another answer states that the C standard for `printf` says that there needs to be at least one leading digit: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2595738/3358272. While this is not C (and not `printf`), it's strongly related.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Seems as though it's not possible within `format()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `format` but can wrap it, then perhaps:

```r
gsub("([-+ ])?0[.]", "\\1.", c("0.5", "-0.5", format(c(0.5, -0.5))))
# [1] ".5"  "-.5" " .5" "-.5"
```